# How do I deactivate scrolling the parent scrollview if the nestedscrollview ends?

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, nestedscrollview

I have a nestedscrollview inside a scrollview and it is working, but I do not want the behavior that if I scroll inside the nestedscrollview and I reach either the top or the bottom, that automatically the scroll keeps on going with the "parent" scrollview.
I find that absolutely annoying.

New App Project with basic activity and this content of content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Root"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollViewRoot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                android:paddingRight="40dp">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <TextView
                        android:text="Nested1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textViewNested1"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1000dp" android:fillViewport="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/black">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="2000dp"
                                  android:orientation="vertical"
                                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
                        <TextView
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1800dp" android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
                <TextView
                        android:text="Nested2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textViewNested2"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                />
                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1000dp" android:fillViewport="true"

                        android:background="@android:color/black">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                  android:layout_height="2000dp"
                                  android:orientation="vertical"
                                  android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                  android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
                        <TextView
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1800dp" android:id="@+id/textView4"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

WRONG: scrolling inside nested can scroll the parent scrollview if top or bottom is reached.

RIGHT: scrolling inside nested can NOT scroll the parent scrollview even if top or bottom is reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, I believe this is not possible. However, you can create your own subclass of `NestedScrollView` and override `onNestedScroll()` and `onNestedFling()` to prevent the passing of "unconsumed" scroll values.

```
class MyNestedScrollView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : NestedScrollView(context, attrs) {

    override fun onNestedScroll(target: View, dxConsumed: Int, dyConsumed: Int, dxUnconsumed: Int, dyUnconsumed: Int, type: Int) {
        super.onNestedScroll(target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, 0, 0, type)
    }

    override fun onNestedFling(target: View, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float, consumed: Boolean): Boolean {
        return super.onNestedFling(target, velocityX, velocityY, true)
    }
}
```

In `onNestedScroll()` we're intercepting `dxUnconsumed` and `dyUnconsumed` and re-writing them to `0`. In `onNestedFling()` we're intercepting `consumed` and re-writing it to `true`.

This makes the system think that the child has always consumed all of the scrolling, so the parent never scrolls in response to a child scroll that hits the boundaries.

Now we just have to use this as the **outer** scrollview in our layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.stackoverflow.MyNestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- ... -->

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="your height here">

            <!-- ... -->

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <!-- ... -->

    </LinearLayout>

</com.example.playground.MyNestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Note that this is potentially dangerous: if your layout is such that it's possible for the child scrollview to fill the screen, there will be no way to "get out" of the child scrollview.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your answer/suggestion. That sounds grounded even if i am surprised that there is no option for that. Of course your are right to point out the danger, that is why i have a right padding to make sure that i can use the outer scrolling.

Comment: I tried your answer, i pasted the code at the end of MainActivity.kt and tried to replace the outer scroll AND after that tried to replace the inner nested Scrolls with "MyNestedScroll" but the result is the same, the app closes instantly after starting. Any thoughts on why that could be?

Comment: -> IT WORKS, AWESOME! Thanks to Ben P.! The outer ScrollView has been replaced with my "com.example.app05basic.MyNestedScrollView", my first try with just "MyNestedScrollView" does not work obviously :)

Comment: Glad to help :)